# Can WebGrid columns be set on the server side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I understand how to add columns with Razor syntax in the view but I was wondering if there is a way to create the WebGridColumns on the server side and hand it off to the WebGrid.GetHtml method on the razor side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor runs on the server, so when you are declaring your columns in your view, the grid is already created on the server. But if by `on the server` you mean `on the controller` that's a different story. But, yes, sure, you could do it. Just define a property on your view model (the class passed to your view by the controller action) which is a collection of the columns.